# I believe my question should not have been closed - how can I get it re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I had a question closed today [Autocomplete feature in AVR Studio 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191671/autocomplete-feature-in-avr-studio-5), which I think is a total nonsense. It concerns to software development, about an IDE functionality. And the user who closed it yet put the reason:

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq. See the FAQ.

It looked for me that the guy even didn't read my question, and chose it to be closed at random.

So, how can I reopen the question?

Comment: Posting here is a good place to start ;)

Comment: Well, I also think that the guy called "cHao, martin clayton, Clive, Matthew Murdoch, Andrew Barber" was wrong...it qualifies more as "Not a real question".

Comment: @Bobby you know we are not to call him by all his five names at once. It disturbs the fragile balance he has managed to establish in his head.

Comment: But why not a real question? For me it's a real question, since I want to enable or disable an IDE functionality and **I don't know how** (and even I could not find it on google or in Atmel site).

Comment: I wonder why it has been closed. The FAQ says:
_____
We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …

 - a specific programming problem
 - a software algorithm
 - software tools commonly used by programmers
 - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
...
_____
So what happened?

Comment: That's my point. The question fits the FAQ totally. There is no reason in closing it.

Comment: Something strange on that question. There's a snarky comment asking what the product is (although the tags have wikis that say what it is, odd with such a small number of questions) but it appears to come from the OP, who surely wouldn't ask himself that?

Comment: @KateGregory: That's most likely a response to the closing or a now deleted comment.

Comment: Your question is very specific to the tool so better be asked in forum dedicated to the tool e.g. [this one](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewforum&f=23) now as this tool is **not** commonly used (at least not by SO programmers, judging from the amount of questions with those tags) it does not fit in the faq.

Comment: @KateGregory: AVRStudio is a very popular IDE for development of Atmel microchips in C and in C++. It's very common for development with Arduino and other AVR chips. It's not popular to general C/C++ developers, due to its related to embedded software.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: [He already figured that out.](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=114102&start=0)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: so can't I ask in SO because it has few tag points here? Even Visual Studio was not popular at the launch time.

Comment: Seriously, sometimes I get the feeling that some moderators do not read their own FAQs. And closing question and as per taste makes this community unpopular. so sad.

Comment: @Bobby nice find! Rego - you can always get the answer as a comment so it's not the end of the world having it Closed. Also keep in mind the question was open for two whole days before getting closed.

Comment: @Steilflug: I don't see any mod involved in this.

Comment: I know [avrfreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=114102&start=0) sure. And if you see the question there, the unique answer I get was from other guy who has the same doubt "I would like to know that too, if it can be enabled then it can be DISABLED..which is what I would want to do."

Comment: @Bobby Sorry, I meant those who have the power to close questions. apologies to the mods.

Comment: And to answer the other questions: I do not consider the questions which go like `In this video you see *x*, how can I do that too?` as good questions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I agree, the problem is not having the question closed. I just want the answer (since I yet don't know it). The problem is that I followed the FAQ, and it's a lack of respect if someone closes it if it fullfits the rules. It's not a professional action, which I understand SO intends to be.

Comment: @Bobby Has there been a "Ask right or die" patrol out there? You cannot expect all ppl to ask the same way. SO would die otherwise.

Comment: @Bobby. Ok, no problem, I can improve the question. And if someone had commented it before I would do it, and would learn much more than just closing.

Comment: Rego - "pure IDE" question might not be against the rules dictated by the faq, but as you see the community itself doesn't like them - not much I can do. The only way I see is to convince moderator that your question is fit then he can re-open and prevent it from getting closed again.

Comment: @Rego, I know what it is, I read the tag wiki. Did you ask what it is? Because at the moment there are two comments, both from you, and the first asks what it is, which appears to me to be a bug on comment attribution, unrelated to your main issue around the closing.

Comment: @Steilflug: Actually, yes. Did you never ask yourself why users with 3k rep gain that power? To keep everything out which shouldn't be in. Also, we never expected people to ask the same way...but you should also not expect to be pardoned.

Comment: Congratulations, it's reopened!

Comment: "but you should also not expect to be pardoned". hm... actually I did. And I feel SO will sooner or later be moved from the throne if power is misused and no mercy is shown. truly regrettable.

Comment: @Steilflug: That discussions has been lead *so many times* to all possible ends...call me if that *really* is going to happen.

Comment: I got all needed votes to reopen the question. Thank you all comments. You were very constructive :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As AVR Studio 5 is a software development tool, closing the question as off-topic is wrong. There could be other reasons to close it, but not because the question is off-topic.

To re-open it, you need 5 users who vote to re-open it. You can also flag it for moderation attention, saying that the question was wrongly closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Bam - and now its been re-opened.

For future reference if you believe that your question has been closed incorrectly then you can either post here on meta or flag the question for moderator attention - I believe you also have the ability to nominate your own question for re-opening as well.

Comment: Yes, he has the required reputation to do so.

Comment: Yes, I got to ask for re-opening, and got all other votes too. Thank you.